# What's next if Super One Click fails?

Tags: rooting, amazon-kindle-fire, motorola-electrify

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I root my Kindle Fire?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17584/how-do-i-root-my-kindle-fire)

I want root, but not enough to reflash or do anything that has a significant chance of harming the phone. In the past I've always used Super One Click, but I've found the Kindle fire can't be rooted Super One Click (though it has specific instructions to root) and neither can my Motorola Electrify after the latest update.

Is there anything to try after Super One Click? It's an amazing catch-all solution but I realized I have never found another solution that doesn't require carrier and device specific roms, recovery mode and lots of other scary things.

Comment: I'm sure if you just wait a bit, someone will figure out how to do it, and then make a One-Click. I'd keep an eye on XDA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The kindle fire was just recently updated and the update removed root from the device, and it broke the Super One Click root method used. Once another root method is found (it may have been already) the developer of Super One Click will most likely update the application to support the Kindle Fire again.

[Here](http://www.engadget.com/2011/12/20/kindle-fires-6-2-1-update-breaks-root-disables-superoneclick-u/) is an article from Engadget talking about the update.

> Just when you thought it was safe to root your Kindle Fire with a single click, Amazon has clamped down on homebrewing enthusiasts. The company has begun pushing out an update for the $199 tablet that breaks the root, disabling the SuperOneClick utility in the process. If you've rooted your tablet and are still running a version of the Amazon-flavored Gingerbread, you're susceptible to the update any time you're connected to a WiFi network. However, if you've already made the leap to another version of Android, such as CM7, you can bypass this and any future software updates. There are some improvements with 6.2.1 though, as smoother scrolling, password protected WiFi use and the ability to remove recently used items from the home screen carousel are among the upgrades. If you're looking to read up on the issue before taking action, roll up your sleeves and hit the links below.

[XDA-Developers Topic](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1400834)

From that thread, if you modify the hosts file and put the amazon update server to point to localhost (127.0.0.1) you will not receive the update, but If you cannot use Super One Click, it sounds like it is too late for you. You seem to already have the update.

Steps to disable the Kindle Automatic Silent Update:

1. Modify /etc/hosts
   `127.0.0.1   s3.amazonaws.com`
2. Disable OTASilentInstall
   Use an app like Titanium Backup and Freeze the OTASilentInstall apk
3. Rename OTASilentInstall (Optional)
   Another option is to use a tool like RootExplorer and rename OTASilentInstall.apk to OTASilentInstall.bak.

As for your Electrify, [I found some steps to root](http://androidforums.com/electrify-all-things-root/422893-i-got-root.html#post3341611) but I don't have the device so I do not know if they still work.

1. Turn on USB Debugging in `Settings -> Applications -> Development -> USB Debugging` - check the box.
2. From the market download and install the Superuser App to your phone. You may be asked to update binaries but you can't till you're rooted. It's OK as is.
3. Download and install the drivers to your PC from the link in step 9 below.
4. Download both the ADB package and the torpedo root file to your PC from the link in step 9 below.
5. Create a folder on your C: drive called Root.
6. Unzip the ADB package to the Root folder and move the torpedo root file there as well.
7. Plug your phone into your PC with the USB cable. Set USB Settings to Charge Only.
8. From your PC click Start:Run: type CMD and click OK.
9. Enter the prompts shown at [How To: Root Motorola Photon 4G](http://briefmobile.com/how-to-root-motorola-photon-4g)

Comment: I believe the new method was already discovered: http://rootzwiki.com/topic/13027-universal-all-firmware-one-click-root-including-261/

Comment: Yes there is at the moment [working root method for the Kindle Fire](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17584/how-do-i-root-my-kindle-fire/17585#17585)