# How do I root my Kindle Fire?

Tags: rooting, amazon-kindle-fire

There are a half-dozen or so questions on the Kindle Fire here where the answers involve having already rooted your device (including my recently-asked [How can I get the Android Market installed on my Kindle Fire?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17338/how-can-i-get-the-android-market-installed-on-my-kindle-fire)). Ok, fine - doing dodgy stuff requires dodgy prep work. But... *How?*

I checked [The Master List of Rooting Techniques](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-device), and found SuperOneClick suggested as the solution for the Fire... But as pleasant as this sounds, in practice this seemingly-easy-to-use tool proves inadequate: [the device has been updated to break the technique it uses](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/17356/3812).

So what's the story (morning glory)? Am I stuck using the device *the way it was intended to be used* <sub><sup>(shudder)</sup></sub>? If not, what *arcane magick* will free me from these chains of conformity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Kindle Fire Utility](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1399889) to easily get root and Market with Google Apps.

It has support for the latest Kindle Fire firmware (6.2.1 currently).

Comment: This tool has 3 detected `virus` on virustotal.com https://www.virustotal.com/file/41108bda0891d2755f0163ee488cabf46ea4a313ceb96a1fc1bf670b6afbd085/analysis/

Comment: This is a very slick tool, took me all of 5 minutes to root my Fire the second time around.

Comment: As of January 2016 the page linked contains this: "WARNING: DO NOT use this on 2nd Generation Devices or you risk bricking your Device."

Answer (score 11):

*BurritoRoot* seems to be the way to go for root on the Kindle Fire. I rooted mine with this tool and [then installed TWRP to get ICS on the Fire.](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17482/how-can-i-install-vanilla-android-on-the-kindle-fire)

BurritoRoot is a simple .apk that needs to be installed. Rooting itself is then easy as with SuperOneClick. **Here are the resources for BurritoRoot:**

- [Offical XDA Thread for BurritoRoot](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1410223)
- [AndroidPolice Blog post **with download link**](http://www.androidpolice.com/2011/12/23/exclusive-how-to-easily-root-the-amazon-kindle-regardless-of-its-software-version/)

---

Once you have root access, Amazon's Prime video service will lock you out of downloading or watching streaming video. Installing [OTA RootKeeper](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.projectvoodoo.otarootkeeper) will let you remove root when it's not needed, and allow video to work.

Comment: There's also a Kindle Fire Utility that works well with Burrito Root. The trouble is getting your windows 7 to recognize the Kindle Fire Device. I was able to do this only after deleting the Android Composite ADB Interface from Device Manager.