# Is it possible to root a Kindle Fire running software version 10.2.6?

Tags: rooting, amazon-kindle-fire

Is it possible to root a Kindle Fire running software version 10.2.6? If so how, and if not will it ever be?

<sup>I can't stand this keyboard! I'd root just for Swype!</sup>

Comment: Did you check with our [master index](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/16575), and find e.g. the question for [Kindle Fire](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17584/16575) there? Besides: Since when do you need to root for Swype? It installed fine on my *Cat Stargate II* (running 4.1.1 and *not* being rooted).

Comment: From [this thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=37102969): > Well Everyone, seems Amazon went and did an update and just wanted to
> confirm so that everyone knows the steps in Root Working 10.2.4 Kindle
> Fire 2 Root made easy still do work on the updated 10.2.6 [Here's tutorial about rooting kindle on 10.2.4.](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2075959)

Comment: Thank you but I believe on the kindle, at least on the older version I've messed with, you could move the kindle file on to the kindle but I couldn't get it to work.